json monitor to alert for any change as chrome extension
I need an extension that monitor an url for every 2 minutes and if any changes happened, play an alert value.
distill can do it buy it is payed. I write a code in python to do so but I get the cloudflare robot filter, so the only way is a extension that refresh a url and look inside the output of json file, and if any change happened, then somehow give me an notification or alert
